# How to disable Chrome's popup notifications?

Tags: google-chrome, notifications

I have Chrome notifications enabled (Bell icon in the taskbar [image]). It works great - especially with [Pushbullet](https://www.pushbullet.com/).

I like the bell being white when there are pending notifications and grayed when all are read. What I hate is the popups. When a new notification arrives, a popup jumps onto the screen, blocking part of it and making me loose concentration. This is extremely **intrusive**!!!

**How can I stop the popups but keep the bell?**

* I have a feeling it's not related to a specific OS.

Comment: I know how it looks. An obvious question. Sorry.

Answer (score -1):

Oh, the solution is easy.

It seems the `Do no disturb` is exactly the answer. Right click on the bell in the taskbar and choose `Do no disturb`.

When in `Do no disturb` mode, the bell is shown white whenever a new notification arrives, but doesn't pop up a window. Doesn't disturb - daaaa.